# Auto size height for rows in Apache POI / Libre Office issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, libreoffice

I am creating a spreadsheet using Apache POI. Some cells have newlines, and I want that the height of the cells fits the height of the content.

I am using the following code :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("Amap");  

    // sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setWrapText(true);

    addRow(sheet,style, (short) 0);

    addRow(sheet,style, (short) 1);

    addRow(sheet,style, (short) 2);   

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test1.xls");
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    System.out.println("OK !");

}

private static HSSFRow addRow(HSSFSheet sheet, HSSFCellStyle style, short rowNumber)
{
    //
    HSSFRow row =   sheet.createRow(rowNumber);   
    // row.setRowStyle(style);     -- has no effect
    // row.setHeight((short)-1);   -- has no effect

    HSSFCell c = row.createCell(0);
    c.setCellStyle(style);
    c.setCellValue("x");

    c = row.createCell(1);
    c.setCellStyle(style);
    c.setCellValue( "a\nb\nc");

    c = row.createCell(2);
    c.setCellStyle(style);
    c.setCellValue( "y");

    return row;

}
```

When I open the generated file with Excel, everything is working well.

But when I open the file with Open Office, only the first line is correct. 
The height of the second and the third lines is too small

An idea ?

Note : I have tried to add row.setRowStyle(style); and row.setHeight((short)-1);
but it seems to have no effect